# How do I make IE8 NOT delete temporary internet files?

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Every time I close Internet Explorer, all temporary files (including cookies) are deleted. IE has a setting for this (Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Security > Empty Temporary Internet Files folder when browser is closed) but the setting is turned off. I tried cycling it on and off again, with no luck. I can open the Temporary Internet Files folder and watch all the files vanish each time IE closes. How can I get the temporary files to stay where they belong?

UPDATE: Unfortunately I no longer have access to this particular computer (it was another employee's laptop, visiting from a satellite office). When I see it again I'll update this with any solution I find.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using IE? http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/8465038.stm

Answer (score 1):

You may have a group policy set that is forcing this behaviour. To check and fix this, do the following:

1. Click Start
2. Click Run
3. Type in `gpedit.msc` and press `Enter`
4. Expand the `Computer Configuration` item
5. Expand the `Administrative Templates` item inside that
6. Expand the `Windows Components` item inside that
7. Expand the `Internet Explorer` item inside that
8. Expand the `Delete Browsing History` item inside that
9. Look at the setting `Configure Delete Browsing History on exit`

If the setting is Enabled, it will override your setting in the browser, and you need to set it to either Disabled or Not Configured.

Comment: This is true. However, I control the group policy for the domain, and I can't imagine how the local group policy would have been changed on this particular computer... unfortunately I don't have access to this computer anymore for testing, so this question is going to be in stasis and unanswerable for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

This may have something to do with the OS security rather than the IE. If you are using vista then check the settings in the user accounts...they may be set to delete on closing.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm running XP SP3. I don't know of any such setting there.